# add user to mongodb via python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to be able to add users to MongoDB so that we can automate MongoDB installs with authentication already baked in. I can successfully add users using pymongo that are read only or are dbOwner by doing this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')   
client.admin.authenticate('siteRootAdmin', 'Test123')
client.testdb.add_user('newTestUser', 'Test123', True)
```

but when I do this following code block to specify roles, it fails:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
client.admin.authenticate('siteRootAdmin', 'Test123')
client.testdb.add_user('newTestUser', 'Test123', False, 'readWrite')
```

with the error:

```
line 10, in <module>
    client.admin.add_user('newTestUser', 'Test123', False, 'readWrite')
TypeError: add_user() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

In the docs it implies that you are able to have optional fields for the user document such as other roles. Has anyone been able to set these correctly? Namely, I want to have readWrite service accounts that can add data to collections but don't have full dbOwner privileges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the workaround:

```
client.testdb.add_user('newTestUser', 'Test123', roles=[{'role':'readWrite','db':'testdb'}])
```

Note: as you're going to set "roles", should leave the 3rd argument (read_only) empty.

Comment: thank you! that syntax for the roles is what i was messing up. i had tried roles = 'readWrite' but didn't notice that mongodb takes both the role and the db in there.

Comment: @rhealitycheck: Actually according to the MongoDB shell syntax, "roles" should always be an array, it could also be roles=["readWrite"] as long as you make sure to run this command after selecting "testdb".

Comment: How do I get a result showing that is was successful or not?

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. `add_user` was deprecated in 3.6 and removed in 4.0. The replacement method `command()` is only available for M10 and larger clusters.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from version 3 `add_user` is [deprecated](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.add_user) and will be removed in later versions. It cause following warning when called:

```
DeprecationWarning: add_user is deprecated and will be removed in PyMongo 4.0. Use db.command with createUser or updateUser instead
```

Above code might be rewritten to

```
client.testdb.command(
    'createUser', 'newTestUser', 
    pwd='Test123',
    roles=[{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'testdb'}]
)
```

Comment: This answer is correct starting with pymongo 4.0. `command()` is only available for M10 and larger clusters.

Comment: Hey @em2er - can you see why your answer is not working for me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76428469/539223