# Can't create user on MongoDB with PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, authorization, pymongo

I have installed MongoDB 2.6.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and pymongo 2.6.3.

I can't create simple user for database other, than admin:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
client.admin.authenticate('siteRootAdmin','passw0rd')
db = client['test']
db.add_user('testAdmin1','passw0rd')

OperationFailure: not authorized for insert on test.system.users
```

Before it I created user siteRootAdmin on admin db with 'root' role. From mongo shell I can add user to test db, but from pymongo have this error.

Comment: Please see the answer in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686749/add-user-to-mongodb-via-python