# Create DB user using PyMongo (v4) and MongoDB (v6)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, digital-ocean

I am using a hosted MongoDB (v6 @ Digital Ocean), and they provided an admin user that I confirmed as valid to create databases, collections, and documents. **I want to add a user that can only 'read' and 'write' in a specific database.**

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066599/539223) that points to the following solution:

```py
client.testdb.command(
    'createUser', 'newUser', pwd='Test123',
    roles=[{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'testdb'}]
)
```

I can execute such a command using my admin db client and get an `ok` response: `{'ok': 1.0, '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': ..., 'signature': {...}, 'operationTime':...}`. Although that is the case, if I query the database for a list of users (i.e., `client.testdb.command('usersInfo')`), I get an empty list.

Moreover, if I try to use such **newUser** to access the **testdb,** I get an `Authentication failed` error. (i.e., I tried to `count_documents({})` -- which works well with my admin client.)

Putting together the documentation for the PyMongo [command database call](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html) and the MongoDB [createUser](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-users/), the above call should indeed work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "hosted MongoDB" meaning Atlas? If so you can't create database users via that command there. See the important note [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-add-mongodb-users/), emphasis added: "_You must use the 
Atlas CLI
, 
Atlas Administration API
, Atlas UI, or a supported integration to add, modify, or delete database users on Atlas database deployments. **Otherwise, Atlas rolls back any user modifications**._"

Comment: That is a great point! I am using Digital Ocean, and your comment made me check [their documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mongodb/how-to/manage-users-and-databases/), which says *You cannot add users to a cluster using the mongo shell.* :(

Answer (score 0):

[@user20042973 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428469/create-db-user-using-pymongo-v4-and-mongodb-v6?noredirect=1#comment134766867_76428469) made me realize I should've checked [Digital Ocean MongoDB User management documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mongodb/how-to/manage-users-and-databases/).

There they say: **You cannot add users to a cluster using the mongo shell. Users must be added to the cluster using the DigitalOcean Control Panel, API, or CLI.**